# A question on building a library - where to ask

Tags: support, closed-questions, site-recommendation

I have asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15634322/812912) on stackoverflow and it was closed as off topic. I would like to ask which site would it be on topic.

I have answered quite a few similar questions on stackoverflow helping others to fight through the nightmare that building a library may become.

Comment: @Mat openwsman not openSwan

Comment: Programmers.SE?

Answer (score 2):

This question is in the gray area.  You can see it as a programming problem, but it isn't about code. But is probably to technical for SuperUser.

I would have tried Ubuntu. According to the [Ubuntu FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq), this question should be acceptable.

But the [Unix & Linux FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) has no section on coding.

Comment: Can you point out why according to stackoverflow the question is not acceptable? In my opinion if a question is in the gray area and may or may not belong on a site descision should always be in favour of the question. After all we try to help not to close as many questions as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure it is not acceptable.  Or I wouldn't have closed it. Unfortunately there is a subjective element, hence the gray area.

Comment: And I'm not the only one. It is almost open (4/5 reopen votes).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the users that closed that question envisioned it being more appropriate.

[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) because if you squint right it's about installing end-user software rather than a programming problem?

[Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) because it's *more* on-topic there?

Some tags can be fairly strict about what's considered topical.

I thought it was a fine question and voted to re-open.